# Customized Exception returning empty message in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, exception

I created my custom Exception `ProduitIntrouvableException` which extends `RuntimeException`

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ProduitIntrouvableException extends RuntimeException {    
    public ProduitIntrouvableException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

and in my controller, I throw it when my `p` is `null` as follow

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;


    @GetMapping(value="/Produits/{id}")
    public MappingJacksonValue afficherUnProduit(@PathVariable int id) throws ProduitIntrouvableException {
        Product p = productDao.findById(id);
       
       if(p==null) 
            throw new ProduitIntrouvableException("Le produit avec l'id "+id+" n'existe pas");

        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter monFiltre = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("prixAchat","id");

        FilterProvider listDeNosFiltres = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("monFiltreDynamique", monFiltre);

        MappingJacksonValue produitsFiltres = new MappingJacksonValue(p);

        produitsFiltres.setFilters(listDeNosFiltres);

        return produitsFiltres;
    }

   
}
```

But I am getting an empty message as follow while I pass a String  `"product not found"` to the constructor but I don't why it is ignored

```
{
   "timestamp": "2020-08-05T16:36:06.825+00:00",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": "",
   "path": "/Produits/40"
}
```

what can be the reason.

Spring Boot version: *2.3.2.RELEASE*

Comment: You have a controller code? Can you add it in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content):

> The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking information to a client. `server.error.include-message` and `server.error.include-binding-errors` can be used to control the inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported values are `always`, `on-param`, and `never`.